# Naudio Recording and playing audio

Tags: vb.net, audio-recording, naudio

I'm using NAudio 1.7 after i gave up on WaveIn p/invoke... anyway, i'm making a VoIP application and the sample code i found used WaveFileWriter to output to disk, i don't want that, so i used the memoryStream overload instead.

The problem is when i try to play the stream after i stop the recording with the SoundPlayer class, it just doesn't play and continues the code, but if i save it as shown below, i can play it in VLC, but if i try to load it from the file itself, it doesn't play either, this time throwing "Wav header damaged" or something, this throws in the stream if i don't set it to Position 0 too.

Do windows sets the wav file header itself when i save it? Why can VLC play it and SoundPlayer can't even if i save it?

```
   Private waveFile As WaveFileWriter
Private newWave As New NAudio.Wave.WaveIn

Private memstream As New MemoryStream

Public Sub StartRecording()
    newWave.WaveFormat = New WaveFormat(44100, 1)

    waveFile = New WaveFileWriter(memstream, newWave.WaveFormat)

    AddHandler newWave.DataAvailable, AddressOf RecordedDataAvailable
    AddHandler newWave.RecordingStopped, AddressOf RecordingStopped

    newWave.StartRecording()
End Sub

Private Sub RecordedDataAvailable(sender As Object, e As NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs)
    If waveFile IsNot Nothing Then
        waveFile.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded)
        waveFile.Flush()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RecordingStopped(sender As Object, e As NAudio.Wave.StoppedEventArgs)
    Dim fileName As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Test"

    File.WriteAllBytes(fileName & ".wav", memstream.GetBuffer)

    memstream.Position = 0

    Dim player As New SoundPlayer(memstream)
    player.Play()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is C# but I think you get the idea ;)
I tried to do same as you did and this works for me.

```
private WaveFileWriter writer;
private WaveIn waveIn;
private MemoryStream memoryStream;

public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  waveIn = new WaveIn();

  waveIn.DataAvailable += OnWaveInDataAvailable;
  waveIn.RecordingStopped += OnWaveInRecordingStopped;
}

private void OnWaveInDataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs waveInEventArgs)
{
  writer.Write(waveInEventArgs.Buffer, 0, waveInEventArgs.BytesRecorded);
  writer.Flush();
}

private void OnWaveInRecordingStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs stoppedEventArgs)
{
  Save();
}

private void Start()
{
  memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
  writer = new WaveFileWriter(new IgnoreDisposeStream(memoryStream), waveIn.WaveFormat);
  waveIn.StartRecording();
}

private void Stop()
{
  waveIn.StopRecording();
}

private void Save()
{
  using (var fileStream = File.Create("test.wav"))
  {
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    memoryStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
  }
}

private void Play()
{
  var soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(memoryStream);
  memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
  soundPlayer.Play();
}

private void OnRecordClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Start();
}

private void OnStopClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Stop();
}

private void OnPlayClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Play();
}
```

}